# Incorrect ESP and EIP after showing some text in Assembly

Tags: text, assembly, console, stack, access-violation

Me again, with the same kind of problems. So, this time I have created a small function that will display some text on the console. You push 2 arguments on the stack, call the function, see the text and return. This is the code:

```
start:
    push dword MyText ; Pointer to the variable from the .data section
    push dword 26 ; Number of characters to write
    call ShowText
    ret

ShowText:
    push ebp
    mov  ebp, esp
    push 0
    push WrittenChars ; Pointer to the variable from the .bss section
    push dword [ebp + 8] ; Number of characters to write
    push dword [ebp + 12] ; MyText
    push dword [StdHandle] ; Value of StdHandle, from the .bss section
    call WriteConsoleA
    pop  ebp
    ret

[section .data]
MyText db 'Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxzw', 0Ah
```

So, the correct values are pushed and retrieved by `WriteConsoleA`, the text is displayed correctly but I still get an *Access Violation Error*, so it looks like ESP is wrong after showing the message. I thought `WriteConsoleA` would clear the stack of its arguments, I don't know what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ShowText` has no pascal calling convetion, so in this case you must adjust the stack yourself.

```
call ShowText
add esp, 08
```

Comment: Well, I thought WriteConsoleA would do it (`retn 14` or something)

Comment: Yeah, it is pascal calling convetion, but the call to your own function doesn't have it.

Comment: Look at my answer, WriteConsoleA will clear the stack, but in your own function call `ShowText` you dont.

Comment: `WriteConsoleA` should remove its parameters... but `ShowText` does not! Either do `ret 8` at the end of `ShowText` or `add esp 8` after the call.

Comment: It should work but it doesn't. Looks like inside the WriteConsoleA block of code the ESP becomes 00000000 at some point (ntdll.77434DFE where I see a `pop esi` instruction) and that's where the problem lies. So, it doesn't even return to my module

Comment: O.K. I found the problem. Thanks for your help

Comment: I think it was because you `push dword MyText` and it should be `push offset MyText` to push the pointer  instead of the first four byes of the string.